# RecyclerView Adapter gives error "The hierarchy of the type RecycleAdapter is inconsistent"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add the new `RecyclerView` to my project inside a `Fragement`. I am following a video tutorial on [Link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k) . When I try to create an adapter for the `RecyclerView`, I start getting this error. I am using Eclipse Juno. I cant figure out the problem. Please help

My code:

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflator;
List <Item> data = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

public RecycleAdapter(Context context, List<Item> data){
    inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int arg1) {
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_staggered_new, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item current = data.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(current.title);
    holder.image.setImageResource(current.image);

}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView image;
    public TextView text;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    }
}
}
```

Both `MyViewHolder` and `RecycleAdapter` are giving error `"The hierarchy of the type RecycleAdapter is inconsistent"`. 
In the extends part of the `RecycleAdapter`, it shows error 
`"Bound mismatch: The type RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> of the type RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>"`.

Any pointers?

Comment: In `onCreateViewHolder` method, shouldn't the second line be `MyViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view)`? I think you missed out `new`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem. The issue was that I was using an older version and v4 support library which does not contain the class android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView class. I replaced my old v4 library with the new version and the error was gone!

Comment: My SDK Manager shows that I am using the latest support libraries but still I get the error.

Comment: TIL - The easiest way to add support libs (after removing them) is via the (right click project)->Android Tools->Add Support Library... 5 plus years of android dev and I never knew that existed...

Answer (score 1):

> I found the problem. The issue was that I was using an older version and v4 support library which does not contain the class android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView class. I replaced my old v4 library with the new version and the error was gone!

It's useful to me, Additional to the Answer:

Eclipse will include a project named "appcompat_v7", We should replaced it's libs ,too.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onBindViewHolder` method you can't cast the RecyclerView.ViewHolder class directly into `MyViewHolder` because the latter is an extension of the former.

You need to perform the cast explicitly, i.e.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder)viewHolder;
    ...
}
```

EDIT

You have multiple compile problems, but the problem you mention is because you are extending the wrong class type. The class should extend like this

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working. I still get same error.. any other ideas?

Comment: The code that you posted should not even compile! Is it really the code you are using? I see compile errors everywhere in your code!

Comment: Yes. I am using this code and the compile error are the same as I have mentioned in the question. In onCreateViewHolder i have changed this line to MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view); adding a missing keyword 'new'

Comment: I am making a custom ViewHolder called MyViewHolder. If i change this, how will i use my custom ViewHolder

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible for me to teach you that here and also way beyond your question.
Here is a good RecyclerView example, study it: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: The sample provided in developer website is doing exactly as i did. I dont think this is the problem. Well thanks anyway!

Comment: @Emir, "The class should extend like this 
`extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`" - this suggestion is not warranted. The official Android tutorial also extends the adapter class in the exact same way the OP does.

Answer (score 0):

one more solution is..

1. Delete jar file from your library.
2. copy `android-support-v7-appcompat` in to workspace from sdk → extra → android → support-v7 → appcompat
3. you will find v4 library in appcompat
4. Right click on appcompat then mark it as library if it is not
5. now right click on your project go to java build path add appcompat as a library.

enjoy